# How do you limit the inclusion of a specific input in a text file

Tags: python, list, random, slice

Im trying to save student's scores in a text file however I have been asked to save the student's last three scores. This sounded fairly straight forward however after attempting various different things I still can't do it. I have been trying to use their names as the variable that changes i.e. if their name is entered more than once.

here is my pitiful best attempt 
please help

```
class_number = prompt_int_big("Before your score is saved ,are you in class 1, 2 or 3? Press the matching number")

    filename = (str(class_number) + "txt")
    if any(name in s for s in filename):
        for score in range (0,3):
            with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                f.write("\n" + str(name) + " also scored " + str(score) +  " on difficulty level " + str(level_of_difficulty) + "\n")
            with open(filename) as f:
                lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
                lines.sort()
            name[-3]
    else:
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write("\n" + str(name) + " scored " + str(score) +  " on difficulty level " + str(level_of_difficulty) + "\n")
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
            lines.sort()
```

Comment: I added some code that you can check out.

Answer (score -1):

```
filename = (str(class_number) + "txt")
```

`class_number` is already a string--because anything a user inputs is a string.  So, let's say the user inputs "1", then you get:

```
filename = "1txt"
```

Then you do:

```
any(name in s for s in filename):
```

When you loop over the string "1txt":

```
for s in filename
```

you get letters back, so you are asking:

```
any(name in "1" ....)
```

...which appears to be nonsensical.

> I have been asked to save the student's last three scores.

Based on your code, I have no inkling what that even remotely means.  How about you post:

1. I have this....
2. I want this....

In the meantime, here's some stuff you can try.  The `shelve` module will make your life much easier:

```
import shelve

fname = "scores"

name = "John"
current_scores = [75, 98]

#shelve will add a .db extension to the filename,
#but you use the name without the .db extension.
with shelve.open(fname) as db:
    old_scores = db.get(name, [])  #db is dictionary-like. Get previously stored scores--if any,
                                   # or return an empty list
    old_scores.extend(current_scores)  #Add the current scores to the old scores.
    db[name] = old_scores[-3:]  #Save the last three scores in the file.


#Time passes....

nane = "John"
current_scores = [67, 80, 41]

with shelve.open(fname) as db:
    old_scores = db.get(name, [])
    old_scores.extend(current_scores)
    old_scores.sort()
    print(old_scores)
    db[name] = old_scores[-3:]


with shelve.open(fname) as db:
    print(db["John"])

--output:--
[41, 67, 75, 80, 98, 98]
[80, 98, 98]
```

Comment: It doesn't work it comes up with a an error on the line: